# Retrieving with balanceOf on ERC20 contract has CALL_EXCEPTION

Tags: ethers.js

Here is the code in nodejs retrieving balance of an ERC20 contact with ethersjs 5.5 after re-deploying the contract:

```
const { ContractFactory } = require('@ethersproject/contracts');
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
router.get("/feeacctbalance", async(req, res) => {
    //let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.privateKeyThis); 
    let acctAddress = process.env.feeAddress;  //<<==wallet address
    let acctPrivKey = process.env.feeAcctPrivateKey;  
    if (!acctAddress || !acctPrivKey) return res.status(401).send("Missing fee acct address/private key");
    if (!global.contractFYX) return res.status(401).send("Missing FYX contract");
    let contractFYX = global.contractFYX;  //<<==ERC20 contract
    let provider = global.provider;  //<<== provider
    try {
        let a = await contractFYX.balanceOf(acctAddress);
        a = a/10**18; //bigNumber returned
        a = a.toFixed(2); //(parseInt(a.toString())/10**18).toFixed(2) return 0.00. .toFixed() shall be done with a number.
        console.log("Acct balance in number : ", a); 
        //
        return res.status(200).send({balance:a, fyxAddress:contractFYX.address, feeAddress:acctAddress});
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("Error in feeacctbalance to : ", err);  //<<==error throws here
        return res.status(400).send("error in fee acct balance check")
    }
});
```

Here is error thrown.

```
Error in feeacctbalance to :  Error: call revert exception (method="balanceOf(address)", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:199:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:208:20)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/interface.js:384:23)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:390:56)
    at step (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:20:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: null,
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  method: 'balanceOf(address)',
  errorArgs: null,
  errorName: null,
  errorSignature: null,
  address: '0x8C4B.......',
  args: [ '0xd335.....' ],
  transaction: {
    data: '0x70a08231000000000000000000000000d3355659195b93c.....',
    to: '0x8C4B6E......',
    from: '0xC0e......'
  }
}
```

However transfer works (no error):

```
  let a = await contractFYX.transfer(to, ethers.utils.parseEther(`${amount}`)); //<<== works!
```

The error only says `CALL_EXCEPTION`. What is the cause of this error?

UPDATE:

Here is the portion of output of `contractFYX` which seems normal:

```
contract FYX :  Contract {
  interface: Interface {
    fragments: [
      [ConstructorFragment],
      [EventFragment],
      [EventFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment],
      [FunctionFragment]
    ],
    _abiCoder: AbiCoder { coerceFunc: null },
    functions: {
      'allowance(address,address)': [FunctionFragment],
      'approve(address,uint256)': [FunctionFragment],
      'balanceOf(address)': [FunctionFragment],
      'decimals()': [FunctionFragment],
      'decreaseAllowance(address,uint256)': [FunctionFragment],
      'increaseAllowance(address,uint256)': [FunctionFragment],
      'name()': [FunctionFragment],
      'symbol()': [FunctionFragment],
      'totalSupply()': [FunctionFragment],
      'transfer(address,uint256)': [FunctionFragment],
      'transferFrom(address,address,uint256)': [FunctionFragment]
    },
    errors: {},
    events: {
```

However output is `0x` from `provider.getCode(AddressOfcontractFYX)`:

```
 _dug provider.getCode(fxydeployAddress) :  0x
```

Shall getCode output the contract functions' code?

Comment: no, getCode() will give you the binary code of the contract

Comment: you should do a debug.traceTransaction() and see what is the revert code text, decode this hex on some online decoder and see what the revert string is. If the revert string is null, then you have to trace the transaction and see what is it doing. If the trace is very short for example, then it could be that `balanceO()` method simply doesn't exist in the contract

Comment: re-deploy worked out. But am not sure what was missing with first deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this error is due to a call exception. It means that the contract's method you are trying to call has thrown an exception or has returned an error during its execution. The reason for the exception is not specified in the error message, but it could be due to a number of reasons, such as an invalid contract address, an error in the contract logic, or an insufficient balance in the account used to perform the call. It is suggested to check the contract code and the parameters being passed to the balanceOf method to determine the cause of the exception.

Comment: transfer works. let a = await contractFYX.transfer(to, ethers.utils.parseEther(`${amount}`));